# I have a list of JSON dicts, I would like to check if the name inside one of the json structures contains a subset of characters

Tags: python, json

As the title states, I would like to check the name field for a certain set of characters. If the name field contains the characters I would like to write it as a string to a new variable.

`Master_Reports` contains a list of JSON structures. I have attached part of one structure below.

```
[{'directory': {'item': [{'last-modified': '2020-03-13 16:17:38',
     'name': '0001628280-20-003532-index-headers.html',
     'type': 'text.gif',
     'size': ''},
    {'last-modified': '2020-03-13 16:17:38',
     'name': '0001628280-20-003532-index.html',
     'type': 'text.gif',
     'size': ''},
    {'last-modified': '2020-03-13 16:17:38',
     'name': 'wkhs-20191231_htm.xml',
     'type': 'text.gif',
     'size': '1315390'},
    {'last-modified': '2020-03-13 16:17:38',
     'name': 'wkhs-20191231_lab.xml',
     'type': 'text.gif',
     'size': '705817'},
    {'last-modified': '2020-03-13 16:17:38',
     'name': 'wkhs-20191231_pre.xml',
     'type': 'text.gif',
     'size': '469764'},
    {'last-modified': '2020-03-13 16:17:38',
     'name': 'wkhs-2019x10kxex1041xi.htm',
     'type': 'text.gif',
     'size': '117747'},
    {'last-modified': '2020-03-13 16:17:38',
     'name': 'wkhs-2019x10kxexx412de.htm',
     'type': 'text.gif',
     'size': '22977'},
    {'last-modified': '2020-03-13 16:17:38',
     'name': 'wkhs-2019x10xkxex1042s.htm',
     'type': 'text.gif',
     'size': '287964'},
    {'last-modified': '2020-03-13 16:17:38',
     'name': 'wkhs-2019x10xkxex211.htm',
     'type': 'text.gif',
     'size': '2275'},
    {'last-modified': '2020-03-13 16:17:38',
     'name': 'wkhs-2019x10xkxex231.htm',
     'type': 'text.gif',
     'size': '2523'}],
   'name': '/Archives/edgar/data/1425287/000162828020003532',
   'parent-dir': '/Archives/edgar/data/1425287'}}
```

Here is my code for accessing the JSON structure:

```
for report in master_reports:
    current_report = master_reports
    for i in range(0,len(current_report['directory']['item'])):
        if 'def' in current_report['directory']['item'][i]['name']:
            file_def = current_report['directory']['item'][i]['name']
```

This gives me the error:
`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Answer (score 0):

`master_reports` is a list of a single item: note that leading left bracket.  Therefore, `current_report[<string>]` is invalid.  Instead, try

```
current_report = master_reports[0]
```

Since `def` is not in any of the names, you now get a clean lack of output.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over master_reports using for loop with single object as report.

Getting `current_report=master_reports` provides current_report also as list.

Thus, trying to get `current_report['directory']` gives error because you are trying to get index using a str value.

Try Below:

```
for report in master_reports:
   for item in report['directory']['item']:
      if 'def' in item['name']:
         file_def = item['name']
```